# Unity2d Screen.width not returning Canvas panel actual screen dimensions in Android devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using LeanTween move method to navigate one canvas panel to the other horizontally.

I read unity forums and found that setting RectTransform values and using Screen.width and height is the right approach. However when I run this in device screen.width is not working as expected. In different device, different behavior. Its not returning the screen dimensions, i searched forums and they are saying screen.width returns game  area width . What does that mean?

What to do to get the actual canvas panel width ?

Canvas Settings Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is the `Canvas` screen size to begin with? When you select the `Canvas` there is a _Canvas scalar script_, what is the `UI Scale mode` set to?

Comment: Hristo, updated my question. please find the attached canvas settings screenshot

Comment: are you using the latest version of `Unity`? If not please consider updating

Comment: The very latest version... Unity 5.6.1f1.
Its not about the latest version. I have been trying this for a week. I couldn't find a proper answer in google too.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Pixel Perfect` **bool** in the `Canvas` script?

Comment: I think... I should try tis link...
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ui-animate-fullscreen-panel-from-off-screen.271751/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my own answer after getting help from the below link

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ui-animate-fullscreen-panel-from-off-screen.271751/

> gameObject.GetComponent().rect.width
>
> gameObject.GetComponent().rect.height